# CS Phone Orders via Admin Credit Declines

Tags: admin, orders

M2 EE 2.1.7

We are having issues with CS phone orders placed via the Admin UI whenever there is a credit decline.

**Steps to reproduce

1. Create a test order for a NEW customer
2. Use an invalid CC (i.e. zip/card mismatch) as to generate a credit decline
3. Fix the CC/zip match such that the card should processes and order go through
4. Attempt to processes the order and we get the error "A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website"**

It's as if the first order charge attempt created the customer in the store, but because it failed it leaves CS agents on that same new customer order page and when you fix/retry it throws the duplicate customer error.

As a result, if a credit card is declined for a new customer, our CS agents have no option but to completely restart the order (generally w/ the customer on the phone) and rebuild from scratch. We sell complex configurable products, so this adds time,costs & frustration.

I bring this here because I just can't imagine this is something that every M2 customer is experiencing. Anyone have any idea on a settings tweak that would fix this? I've looked all around Stores>Configuration>(Orders & Customers)

Thanks in advance for any insight.